# Setting a min. range before fetching data

Tags: sql

i have a table which has localities numbered with unique numbers. Each locality has some buildings numbered that have the status as Activated = Y or N. i want to pick localities which have the min Building Activated = 'Y'  count of 15.

Sample Data :

```
Locality    ACTIVATED
1   Y
1   Y
1   N
1   N
1   N
1   N
2   Y
2   Y
2   Y
2   Y
2   Y
```

Eg : i need count of locality that with min. 5 Y in ACTIVATED Column

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.   Tag the question with the database you are using.  A SQL Fiddle can also be very helpful.

Comment: Plz share your schema.

Comment: @DonCallisto Rather SELECT TOP 15

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MySQL client version: 5.5.25

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.*
FROM Localities l
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Building b
       WHERE b.LocalityNumber = l.LocalityNumber
         AND b.Activated = 'Y') >= 15
```